# React. function does not save from API first run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I am sorry if there is a similar question out there that I missed.
My problem is that when I do send a request to the API I get results back (Status 200) and it does save it in server response but I can't save it in authenticatedUser first run. but when I run it a second time it does save in authenticatedUser

I have tried basically two different ways and both give kinda the same result. (that I need to call the function twice)

First: (it updates the serverResponse but goes to error and do not update AuthenticatedUser)

```js
    const RequestLogin = async () => {
        try {
            setServerResponse(await BackendAPIService.RequestLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password))
            if (serverResponse.status === 200) {
                setAuthenticatedUser(serverResponse.data)
                history.goBack()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error?.response?.data?.detail == undefined ? error?.response?.data == undefined ? 'ServerError Plase wait or contanct support' : error?.response?.data : error?.response?.data?.detail)
        }
    }
```

Second Way: (it updates the serverResponse but not AuthenticatedUser )

```js
    const handleSuccess = () => {
        setAuthenticatedUser(serverResponse.data)
        history.goBack()
    }

    const RequestLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await BackendAPIService.RequestLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password)
            setServerResponse(data)
            serverResponse && handleSuccess()

        } catch (error) {
            setError(error?.response?.data?.detail == undefined ? error?.response?.data == undefined ? 'ServerError Plase wait or contanct support' : error?.response?.data : error?.response?.data?.detail)
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code

```js
import { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import BackendAPIService from '../../assets/api/service/BackendAPIService'
import { UserContext } from '../../assets/provider/UserProvider'
import RoutingPath from '../../routes/RoutingPath'
import LocalStorage from '../../assets/cache/LocalStorage'

export const SignIn = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const [AuthenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useContext(UserContext)
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: '', password: '', })
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState<any>()
    const [Error, setError] = useState<string>('')
    const [remberMe,setRemberMe] = useState<boolean>(false)


    const history = useHistory()

    const showError = () => { return Error == '' ? '' : <div className="ErrorText">{Error}<br /></div> }

    const RequestLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await BackendAPIService.RequestLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password)
            setServerResponse(response)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setAuthenticatedUser(response.data)
                if (remberMe) localStorage.setItem(LocalStorage.user, response.data.hashedID)
                history.goBack()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error?.response?.data?.detail == undefined ? error?.response?.data == undefined ? 'ServerError Plase wait or contanct support' : error?.response?.data : error?.response?.data?.detail)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="email" value={credentials.email} placeholder="Enter your e-mail" onChange={
                (event) => setCredentials({ email: event.target.value, password: credentials.password })
            } />
            <br />
            <input type="password" value={credentials.password} placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={
                (event) => setCredentials({ email: credentials.email, password: event.target.value })
            } />
            <br />
            {showError()}
            <button onClick={() => RequestLogin()}>Login</button>
            Remember Me:<input className="rememberMe" type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => setRemberMe(event.target.checked)} />
            <br />
            <p className="ForgotPassword" onClick={() => { history.push(RoutingPath.forgotPassword) }}>Forgot Password?</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `handleSucess` spelling ;)

Comment: what is setAuthenticatedUser and setServerResponse?

Comment: @epascarello useState and useContext
 const [AuthenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useContext(UserContext)
 const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState<any>()

Comment: Why is handleSuccess using serverResponse without it being provided as an argument? Is it a global variable? "Doesn't update the authenticatedUser" - can you elaborate on whats happening instead? Did you try to debug it and see is "serverResponse" value is there? If it is, what is it doing so different that its not updating the user?

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev it is a global for that file.

authenticatedUser is still undefind after first run. and serverResponse hold an object called user from the API.  and for what it do isntad, in frist exaple goes to the catch bard and second expamle does nothing

Comment: @Tehpson how is something you set to a global variable is still undefined? Can you show all the code needed as it seems some methods are black boxes that do not allow the value to pass through.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev it is already solved. and in react you can set useStates initalvalue as undefind

Comment: @Tehpson I know its solved, but more information can be added so that anyone else who stumble upon this problem and find this question can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to setAuthenticatedUser(serverResponse.data) immediately after setting serverResponse state (i.e. in the same render). Use the actual response that's in your scope rather than trying to access state right after you set it.

```
const RequestLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await BackendAPIService.RequestLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password);
            setServerResponse(response);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setAuthenticatedUser(response.data)
                history.goBack()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error?.response?.data?.detail == undefined ? error?.response?.data == undefined ? 'ServerError Plase wait or contanct support' : error?.response?.data : error?.response?.data?.detail)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. and i also understand why this work and not mine. Thansk you agian